# In beamer equations don't look like in article

Tags: beamer, equations, symbols, brackets, article

I am writing a thesis and I began write as a article. I thought it is easy convert to beamer. Now I have some problems. In `equnarray` and `$`, parenthesis, bracket and `\bigoplus` don't seem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\mode<presentation>{\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumerate}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{eqnarray*}
        x\bigoplus y=max\left\{x,y\right\}\\
        x\bigotimes y=x+y
    \end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

In article:
[image]
In beamer:
[image]

Comment: You have a problem with the `enumerate` package with the option `[shortlabels]` (it clashes with `TikZ` package).

Comment: It must be a maths font error. What happens if you comment out the `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.  By the way your "max" is a function so you should `\DeclareMathOperator\max{max}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is an option clash, therefore I removed `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumerate}`.

The main error message is `Too many math alphabets used in version normal.`, so either use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` or `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, but not both at the same time.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}
%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumerate}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{eqnarray*}
        x\bigoplus y=\max\left\{x,y\right\}\\
        x\bigotimes y=x+y
    \end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}
%\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumerate}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{eqnarray*}
        x\bigoplus y=\max\left\{x,y\right\}\\
        x\bigotimes y=x+y
    \end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: off-topic: correct is `x\bigoplus y=\max\left\{x,y\right\}\\` :)